# iOS7 - enabledRemoteNotificationTypes return UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone but in Settings.app Alert,Badge and Sound are enabled

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have following code in view controller button action:

```
- (IBAction)requestPermissions:(id)sender
{
  DDLogInfo(@"Start permission requesting.");

  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
  } else {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didBecomeActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
  }
}
```

After registration is finished `didBecomeActive` notification is posted and I'm making a check what user have done:

```
-(void)didBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone){
// if user decline 
}
} else {
 // if user accept
}
```

So my problem is: If user decline to receive push notifications and later decides to enable them (Settings->Notification center->My App), there is a surprise: 'Alert' ,'Badge' and 'Sound' are enabled in Settings, but app returns  `UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone`.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Note: I know these methods are deprecated, so please don't tell me to use `registerForRemoteNotifications:` and `UIUserNotificationSettings`, it is already done.

Comment: On what iOS version your problem appear?

Comment: It is written in title - iOS 7.1.2 :)

Comment: Why -1, by the way? What isn't clear?

Answer (score 2):

Well, possibly it returns a proper value after app restart, could you check that? I've found situations where iOS automatically kills your app when changing permissions in Settings while your app is in the background, f.e. Photos feed access; I suppose it's just a buggy implementation in iOS in this case, this wouldn't surprise me. I think I've hitted this situation you describe as well, and after finding it's returning invalid/old values until restart, I gave up and make the flow count with required restart.

Anyway, I don't think there's anything you could do about it.

Comment: Thanks for answer:  Basically problem is when move registerForRemoteNotificationTypes from AppDelegate to view controller action method.There is an option to leave registration in app delegate, but I don't think it is good.

Comment: Also, I restart permissions alert every time, tried with 'Erase all contents and settings', and situation is same.

Comment: Does it mean it works when leaving the notification in App Delegate? I think this shouldn't differ. But as you say, I usually delegate this to internal instance of Notification Centre, along with other NSNotificationCenter stuff by recalling to have all the stuff on once place.

Comment: When leave 'registerForRemoteNotificationTypes' in App Delegate and user decline 'Badge','Alert' and 'Sound' this settings are disabled. But if  'registerForRemoteNotificationTypes' is in Action method of View Controller 'Badge','Alert' and 'Sound' this settings are shown as enabled, even if they aren't. By the way  what exactly you do with NSNotificationCenter? Can you show me some code?

Comment: Well, that's weird, but I'm not surprised as there are many weirdos in iOS black box. Ad Notification Center, nothing special, I just generally use NC as a subclass of NSObject, exported to project via header prefix and use it to register notifications, re-call observers, notification posting and handle In-App notifications along with its UI. No special hacks against iOS notifications system.

Comment: Hi again, I cannot accept your answer just because I can't confirm it is a buggy apple code :)

Comment: That's all right, I understand, we'll have this confirmed once it starts to work, I hope we are going to be surprised in future iOS releases. :)